# Are fonts from the google_fonts package for flutter automatically stored in cache?

Tags: flutter

I'm reading the google_fonts documentation and I'm mostly here for clarification.

"With the google_fonts package, .ttf or .otf files do not need to be stored in your assets folder and mapped in the pubspec. **Instead, they can be fetched once via http at runtime, and cached in the app's file system.** This is ideal for development, and can be the preferred behavior for production apps that are looking to reduce the app bundle size."

Do I have to follow an extra step to cache the fonts, or should it happen automatically assuming I use the following code from the documentation:

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
),
```

I think I'm tripped up by the wording here. When it says the fonts *can* be fetched once at runtime, I want to know if that's what happens by default.

Comment: first it will try to read font from system, if not found get via http and cache font file to device. https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/blob/master/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart#L127

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing some font library research for custom fonts, and what I see in Google Fonts per:

https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/blob/develop/lib/src/google_fonts_variant.dart

Looks pretty directly that it does per the code:

```
Future<void> saveFontToDeviceFileSystem(String name, List<int> bytes) async {
  final file = await _localFile(name);
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
}

Future<ByteData> loadFontFromDeviceFileSystem(String name) async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile(name);
    final fileExists = file.existsSync();
    if (fileExists) {
      List<int> contents = await file.readAsBytes();
      if (contents != null && contents.isNotEmpty) {
        return ByteData.view(Uint8List.fromList(contents).buffer);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

At runtime it checks in:

https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/blob/develop/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart

```
Future<void> loadFontIfNecessary(GoogleFontsDescriptor descriptor) async {
  final familyWithVariantString = descriptor.familyWithVariant.toString();
  final fontName = descriptor.familyWithVariant.toApiFilenamePrefix();
  // If this font has already already loaded or is loading, then there is no
  // need to attempt to load it again, unless the attempted load results in an
  // error.
  if (_loadedFonts.contains(familyWithVariantString)) {
    return;
  } else {
    _loadedFonts.add(familyWithVariantString);
  }

  try {
    Future<ByteData> byteData;

    // Check if this font can be loaded by the pre-bundled assets.
    final assetManifestJson = await assetManifest.json();
    final assetPath = _findFamilyWithVariantAssetPath(
      descriptor.familyWithVariant,
      assetManifestJson,
    );
    if (assetPath != null) {
      byteData = rootBundle.load(assetPath);
    }
    if (await byteData != null) {
      return _loadFontByteData(familyWithVariantString, byteData);
    }

    // Check if this font can be loaded from the device file system.
    byteData = file_io.loadFontFromDeviceFileSystem(familyWithVariantString);

    if (await byteData != null) {
      return _loadFontByteData(familyWithVariantString, byteData);
```

While it doesn't work for me directly, it is the base of dynamic_fonts which I am evaluating:

https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_fonts/

I agree though, the wording isn't totally clear if its handling caching or not but looks to be per the code.